# Getting bash: java: command not found while using java -jar

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, codeception, acceptance-testing

I'm new to everything I mention here so this makes it a little bit hard for me.
I wanted to install Selenium driver to run codeception acceptance tests.

I downloaded [selenium server](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/), copied the **selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar** in the same path as I save my tests.

then I ran the `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar` on Git Bash according to codeception help on installing [Web Driver](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver). I got the error

> bash: java: command not found

anybody knows what's wrong here?

Comment: is your environment variable "JAVA_HOME" set?

Answer (score 0):

java is not installed or it isn't present in PATH.

Comment: Yeah! :D
Thanks :)